Prometheus promauto counter throws too many arguments
I am using the prometheus library "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promauto"
to create a counter to do a inc with a parameter.
I am initializing the counter as below:
 someCounterName := promauto.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "SomeCount",
    })

The source code for inc shows:
func (c Counter) Inc(i int64) {
    //TODO implement me
    panic("implement me")
}

Intellij comppiler does not show errors. When go complies it shows this error saying the error as below:
too many arguments in call to someCounterName
Imports
"github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
"github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promauto"

I tried doing a cache clear using
go clean cache.
This did not help. Any insight would be helpful.

Judging from the error you are trying to call someCounterName as if it were a function. Did you forget .Inc()?

I guess you are calling a wrong function Inc which has arg. I couldn't locate the one you showed in promauto package. Just call Inc() w/o any args.

Yes fixed it without arguemnts calling inc(). For some intelligence decompiler did not show compile errors
